# "Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined" when Angular router guard canActivate returns no on route change

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

In an Angular 7 application where I use a router with main state and child states, a Guard helps me to prevent users to access states they cannot access at a given moment during a form filling process. So basically my Guard checks that all previous states forms are valid before letting user access next step. All is fine when Guard's canActivate method says its ok, but when it returns false I get this error which i can't understand in console:

```
zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of undefined
    at i.t._activate (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at i.t.show (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.i._jQueryInterface [as tab] (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (bootstrap.min.js:6)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.y.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
t._activate @ bootstrap.min.js:6
t.show @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
i._jQueryInterface @ bootstrap.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
```

Here i'm stuck with this error and trying to run the app step by step. Any idea of the problems origin or a suggestion of where to search? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code of the guard and make an example in stackblitz.com?

Comment: ok, i try to make a small app reproducing my problem, thanks.

Comment: Seeing the stacktrace, I think the problems comes from jquery and bootstrap. Are you sure you need bootstrap and jquery in a angular app?

Comment: yes actually bootstrap/jquery are useful on my form inputs, unfortunately.